# Cannot open include file: 'sys/mman.h': No such file or directory

Tags: python, pip, raspberry-pi3

I was trying to install the raspberry's GPIO pin controller library using this command on windows on vscode editors powershell terminal. How I am trying to control the raspberry pi3 pins is I am simulating the hardware design in a proteus8.13 simulation software not on an actual raspberry pi3 hardware?

```
pip install RPi.GPIO
```

but keeps getting the following error:-

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sys/mman.h': No such file or directory      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.36.32532\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for RPI.GPIO
Failed to build RPI.GPIO
ERROR: Could not build wheels for RPI.GPIO, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I already downloaded Visual Studio 2022 with the `C++ build tools` and add the necessary environment variables, but keeps getting the above error I mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

Are you running `pip install RPI.GPIO` remotely on the respberry pi or you want to install the library on your device directly what do you mean by running the command on vscode editor's terminal?

It's not possible to install `RPI.GPIO` library on Windows because it's supposed to be installed on Raspberry pi directly.

I don't have an access to a Windows device but technically you can install `PRI.GPIO` on OS with a linux kernel thus run `pip install RPI.GPIO` inside WSL 2 terminal it may be installed successfully but it won't run since it requires raspberry pi hardware.

Comment: i was using proteus8.13 for hardware simulation of raspberry pi ?

Comment: Proteus has a built-in code editor try to write you code and compile & execute your code there.

Comment: [wokwi](https://wokwi.com/projects/new/pi-pico), they have a Pi-pico raspberry pi simulator give it a try!

Comment: yes i am using Proteus built-in code editor to write and compile & execute my code, but for installation i used vs code terminal i do not now if there is any way to do that on proteus, does it have built in terminal?